# The sql command automatically creates a row number

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

mytable:

```
name     family
-----------------
a        aa
b        bb
c        cc
d        dd
```

My desired output by SQL Code(by direction Select):

```
Row   name     family
-----------------
1     a        aa
2     b        bb
3     c        cc
4     d        dd
```

Comment: Are you ordering by name or family? The sample data could be either.

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) function, it is one of the [Ranking Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in SQL Server:

```
WITH CTE
(
   SELECT
     ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name) AS row, 
     name, 
     family
   FROM tablename
)
SELECT * FROM CTE;
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE
(
      name VARCHAR(20)
    , family VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO @temp (name, family)
VALUES 
    ('a', 'aa'),
    ('b', 'bb'),
    ('c', 'cc'),
    ('d', 'dd')

SELECT
      [Row] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1))
    , name
    , family
FROM @temp
```

**Output:**

```
Row   name    family
----- ------- -------
1     a       aa
2     b       bb
3     c       cc
4     d       dd
```